# scrapy shell is not showing me any element

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, terminal, scrapy

i am crawling this page:
https://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2015/8/5/huge-4-br-on-a-high-floor-now-available-2/?related_ads=1&back=ZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUuY29tL3Byb3BlcnR5LWZvci1yZW50L3Jlc2lkZW50aWFsL2FwYXJ0bWVudGZsYXQv

using scrapy shell command line

i try to extract any element but i keep getting empty though when i run a spider as a python code and extract the elements from the spider every thing works find

please look at this screenshot for executing from my terminal

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `response.xpath(".//div")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are prepending `./` which makes the XPath context-specific to the root node of the tree. In other words `./div` would make it search for the `div` element which is a direct child of `html`.

Instead, use `.//` to search anywhere inside the HTML:

```
response.xpath(".//div")
```

Comment: rocky mistake by me. i can't believe i forgot this :X :X thanks man. you are the python gold. i am about to make a question about documenting my python final project. could you help please

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli okay, create a question and throw me a link here. Thanks.

Comment: thank u, this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435622/python-auto-documenting-the-project in advance thanks