# python "auto" documenting the project

Tags: python, python-2.7

First I know there is nothing completely to auto documenting, I am aware of that, i am just asking about any tool that could help me to make the documentation fast.

I have almost finished my scrapy projects and I want to document the code, **yes I am bad i didn't do the documentation during the development:**

Anyway, I found sphinx which sounds good but really it needs hard work to document, plus it just provides a web pages for the projects, I was looking for some tools that could do something like this:

if my code is:

```
def myfucnction(var1, var2):
   return 3+3;
```

so the code should edit the source code and add the needed rst syntax like `"""`

then i find sphinx api doc which sounds good, it generates a lot of files, a little bit missy but i can edit them. nevertheless it didn't add anything about the functions and classes in my code, it just created rst files for each python script i have. that is not banefial to me because for my manager, we need **for each** function the inputs documented and the return documented and a little bit text about the function (really little bit)

here i am asking for your suggestions, helps. this is my first python project, hope you help me

#### Update1

I was expecting that there could be a tool that generates templates for documentation and I update these templates

Comment: `add the needed rst syntax like """` actually it is docstring syntax. Sphinx just generates documenation based on docstrings.

Comment: Writing good documentation is hard. You have to think. A tool can't do this for you.

Comment: @PeterWood so your suggestion is to add the document myself? I was expecting that there could be a tool that generates templates for documentation and I update these templates

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli writing such a template generator would be pretty easy. Just parse each file looking for `def` statements and insert comment blocks right after them. Or you can use something like flake which will automatically point out the places where you need to insert docstrings.

Comment: @RishavKundu do you mean using this ? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8 ? and will this flake add the templates to my code? or it is me who have to read the output of this flake and then document my code?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli yes it will give you all the places where you can insert your docstrings. But what I am saying is that you can write a simple program in Python which will read your other python scripts and insert docstrings for you.

Comment: @RishavKundu writing my own code for this sounds so old fashion, i don't think that is a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to get help of modern IDEs.

For instance, [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) has a built-in "Missing docstring" code inspection with an ability to fix it - insert a docstring. For instance, if you have this code:

```
def test(a, b):
    return a + b
```

and if you would inspect it with PyCharm, after applying the "Missing docstring" fix, Pycharm would auto generate a docstring template in a desired format:

```
def test(a, b):
    """

    :param a: 
    :param b: 
    :return: 
    """
    return a + b
```

There is more to that - it's quite configurable:

- [Creating Documentation Comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-documentation-comments.html)
- [Using Docstrings to Specify Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html)

Comment: okay now i am using Sublime text 2 on mac for writing python. if i install pycharm and added these documentations, will sphinx add them automatically to the web pages it generates ?

Comment: does the community edition of pycharm have these features please? Plus one

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli yes, it does.

Comment: sorry again, but i have already installed (in the past) pycharm and it was so heavy to load, so i would like to ask you if it provides things rather than adding these `"""` because if not, i can do that myself and better than installing something on my machine. does it generate documentations like sphinx ? any other features please? again sorry for keep asking

Comment: plus one important things, when i add these `"""` is there anything that can generate a web page after parsing these documented python code?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli which editor to choose is up to you. I'm just pointing out that PyCharm has this feature built-in and it fits your use case perfectly. Generating an HTML out of your docstrings is what `sphinx` can help you with - though this is a different question.

Comment: @alecxe so to sum up. the solution could be to add the docstrings (either myself or using pycharm) then ask sphinx to generates the web pages. right?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli well, PyCharm might create templates for you, but you would need to improve them manually anyway. Next time make it a habit and write docstrings during the development, or before (see Documentation Driven Development).

Comment: your last comment confused me, did you mean that pycharm will not add the docstrings including the input variables and the return type for all the functions?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I just meant that it would auto-generate the docstrings to a certain extent, it would not do all of the work for you. You would have to manually review the docstrings it auto-generated and improve them describing what a particular function/method/class/module does, return value types, constraints etc. It's not easy to write clear and detailed documentation and then keep it up-to-date with the code - all of this requires an effort.